# No longer can use vglm for underdispersed count data in R?

Tags: r, poisson, vgam

I've read elsewhere that the VGAM package can be used to model underdispersed count data via the genpoisson families. However, when I look up the help file for genpoisson0, genpoisson1, and genpoisson2 they all say the following:

"In theory the λ parameter is allowed to be negative to handle underdispersion, however this is no longer supported, hence 0 < λ < 1."

"In theory the \varphi parameter might be allowed to be less than unity to handle underdispersion but this is not supported."

"In theory the α parameter might be allowed to be negative to handle underdispersion but this is not supported."

Where can I go to handle underdispersion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use *quasilikelihood* methods, e.g. `family=quasipoisson` in `glm()` (in base R)
- the `glmmTMB` package supports COM-Poisson (`family = compois`) and generalized Poisson (`family = genpois`) conditional distributions.

It's not clear to me whether the reasons discussed (briefly) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/549802/2126) for why underdispersed generalized Poisson distributions are no longer supported in `VGAM` also apply to the implementation in `glmmTMB` ...

There is some discussion of the `glmmTMB` parameterizations/implementations of COM-Poisson and generalized Poisson in Brooks et al (2019).

---

Brooks, Mollie E., Kasper Kristensen, Maria Rosa Darrigo, Paulo Rubim, María Uriarte, Emilio Bruna, and Benjamin M. Bolker. “Statistical Modeling of Patterns in Annual Reproductive Rates.” Ecology 100, no. 7 (2019): e02706. https://doi.org/10.1002/ecy.2706.

Comment: After reading the paper, I think I'll look at COM-Poisson. Thanks.